# Objective C: Drop Area

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

i am trying to have a drop area of an item and when the item drops on the wrong area it will go back to its original position.

here's my code:

```
UITouch *touch =[[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint dropPoint = CGPointMake(60, 520);
    location = [touch locationInView:self.view];


if([touch view]==image1 && CGPointEqualToPoint(location, dropPoint)){
   [image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 520, 150, 184)];
    return;
} else
{
    [dad setFrame:CGRectMake(530, 225, 150, 184)];
}
```

i think my mistake is that, i used CGPoint for the drop area and it needs to be exactly position on that point i've declared before if runs the commands, am i right?

now i don't know how to fix it...

thanks in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CGPoint takes in CGFloats (which means that the location has to be so precise I don't think most users can make it), my best guess is that it's the dropPoint issue. One solution is to make a drop area using CGRect and compare using:

```
CGRectContainsPoint(dropRect, location);
```

Note that the comparison:

```
[touch view] == image1
```

Will return true if the two pointers point to the same object (also as long as you are aware that the view property of UITouches returns the original view the touch occurred in and not the current view).

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
[touch view]==image1
```

compares the pointers not the objects to which they point. This may be your problem. An easy solution is to use the `tag` property for `UIView`s to keep track of which image is currently the `view` for `touch`.